Remove assignments of all product properties of specific product id using Shopware 6 Admin-API
In Shopware 6 (6.6.3.1) using Admin-API (JSON) I try to remove the assignments of all product properties of a specific product providing a product id (UUID) without removing the product properties themselves.
In the Shopware database I have a (many to many) mapping table product_property with field product_id (01905eac61987a93beb9e20f4261d4d3) and property_group_option_id with 6 assigned property UUIDs 01900679e33470309437656162396139, 01900679e33470658634383038656636, 01900679e3347163a238396435363461, 01900679e3347337a530333332346138, 01900679e33474389765346439643830, 01900679e33474648639643832313233.
These assignments I try to remove product by product by Admin-API.
I tried with the following API request endpoint path:
https://www.example.org/api/_action/sync

And the following API request body:
{
  "delete-product-property": {
  "entity": "product_property",
  "action": "delete",
  "payload": 
    [
      {
        "productId": "01904e1b2fcf713f8d7f8a8e0481ecd2",
        "optionId": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}

But I can't provide the optionIDs of the product properties, so maybe I need some additional associations in the JSON body?
Is my approach fundamentally wrong?
I tried to get matching examples at https://shopware.stoplight.io and https://swagger.docs.fos.gg and searched for a match at stackoverflow using "[shopware] rest-api" and "[shopware] api property".
